# How do make a persistence sign in in React Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm building an app using Firebase Auth, I have a sign in function but it doesn't persist. How do I make that sign in function persist so that a user can refresh the app or open the app in another tab but still is signed in?
Here is my sign in:

```
const signIn = () => {
        auth
            .signInWithPopup(provider)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
                dispatch({
                    type: actionTypes.SET_USER,
                    user: result.user,
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert(error.message);
            });
        history.push("/account");
    };
```

my firebase.js:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
   // firebase config
  };

  const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  const storage = firebase.storage();

  export { auth, provider, storage };
  export default db;
```

I've tried this:

```
const signIn = async () => {
        await auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);
        await auth
            .signInWithPopup(provider)
            .then((result) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: actionTypes.SET_USER,
                    user: result.user,
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert(error.message);
            });
        history.push("/account");
    };
```

and this:

```
const login = () => {
        auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
        .then(function() {
          return auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
                  .then((result) => {
                      console.log(result);
                      dispatch({
                          type: actionTypes.SET_USER,
                          user: result.user,
                      });
                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                      alert(error.message);
                  });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
        });
    };
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks

**EDIT #1**

Here is my reducer.js:

```
export const initialState = {
    user: null
};

export const actionTypes = {
    SET_USER: "SET_USER"
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    console.log(action);

    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.SET_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.user
            }
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

And in App.js, I check if the user is not null:

```
<Router>
      <div className="app">
        {!user ? (
          <>
            <PublicTopbar />
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/sign-in">
                <Login />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </>
        ) : (
          // My components
        )
```

Even after I signed in, when I open another tab, the app keeps asking me to login again

Comment: What doesn't work about it?  What are you observing that can be reproduced?  Please edit the question to be clear.

Comment: the sign in does not persist (after I signed in, when I refresh or open another tap of the app, it requires me to sign in again)

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail, showing the code that doesn't work the way you expect.  We should be able to copy what you have and reproduce your observation.  I can see no code here that checks to see if the user is signed in and renders accordingly.  That doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated the question, please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: I still don't see any code that checks the sign in state of the user.

Answer (score 2):

On most platforms you don't have to configure persistence, as it's set by default.

What you *will* need to do is detect whether the user is signed in using an `onAuthStateChanged` handler as shown in the documentation on [getting the signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Once `user` has a value in this callback you can be sure the user is signed in. Note that the listener may initially be called with `null` while the page is loading, as Firebase Authentication may at that moment be verifying the persisted credentials.

Comment: I have updated the question, please take a look. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use local storage. The below code is written with Redux Actions, but you can modify it for normal post request function.

```
//Firebase Api
const loginInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL:"https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key="+API_KEY
})

//Send login request to Firebase
const login = (email, password) =>
{
    const postData = {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        returnSecureToken:true
    }

    return dispatch =>
    {

        loginInstance.post("", postData)
            .then(res =>
            {
                dispatch(setLoginStatus(res.data.idToken, res.data.email))

                localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.idToken); //<==
                localStorage.setItem("email", res.data.email);  //<==

            })
            .catch(err => dispatch(error(err.response.data.error.message)))
    }
}

//Check if already logged in 
const checkLoginStatus = () =>
{
    return dispatch =>
    {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token") //<==
        const email = localStorage.getItem("email")//<==

        if (!token)
        dispatch(logout())
        else
        dispatch(setLoginStatus(token, email))  
    }
}

//Logout & Cleanup Localstorage
const logout = () =>
{
    localStorage.removeItem("token") //<==
    localStorage.removeItem("email")//<==

    return {
        type: actionTypes.LOGOUT,
    }
}



  //Check if already logged in
  useEffect(() =>
  {
    dispatch(actions.checkLoginStatus())
  }, [])


 // Normal Routes
  if(isAuthenticated)
  {
   //Do Something
  }
```

Comment: I hvae updated the question, please take a look. Thank you

Comment: Did you try the firebase login request in this method which i posted earlier.

//Firebase Api
const loginInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL:"https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key="+API_KEY
})